# Creating gtsummary() table with sums of continuous outcome stratified by categorical exposure status

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am attempting to create a table showing counts of (continuous) outcome events stratified by (categorical) exposure status. I want the output to be a table with a single column (with values indicating # of events), and the rows indicating binary yes/no for each exposure status.

My underlying data includes:

1. outcome_var: a continuous variable with values ranging from 0 - 8.
2. exposure_1: a binary variable with values of 1/yes and 0/no
3. exposure_2: another binary variable same as above

```
tbl_1 <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(outcome_var, exposure_1, exposure_2) %>%
  tbl_summary(
              type = c("exposure_1" = "categorical", "exposure_2" = "categorical", "outcome_var" = "continuous"),
              statistic = c(outcome_var) ~ "{sum}",
              label = list(exposure_1 ~ "exposure 1", exposure_2 ~ "exposure 2", outcome_var ~ "outcome"),
              missing = "no",
              percent = "column") %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "n, %") %>%
  remove_row_type("record_id", type = c("all"))
```

Unfortunately, this results in a table with counts of exposure status rather than the sum of the outcome. There is a row for outcome_var with the sum, but I want the entire column to reflect the outcome_var values.

Ideally, each row would include the total number of outcome events for each level of exposure as well as the proportion (count of events/N).

I also tried setting by = outcome_var, but this created 9 columns (for values 0 - 8). Then, I tried hiding all of these columns and creating a summary column, but I realized that the row values were just the counts of exposure status and not the counts of the outcome. Wondering if I need to use tbl_custom_summary to do what I want.

Thank you!

Desired table:
SEE IMAGE   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyHYR.png

Dput output:

`````
structure(list(outcome_var = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1), levels = c("No", "Yes")), exposure_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"0"), class = "factor"), exposure_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-239L))````
`````

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reprex (https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) including data so we can test on our machines. Also, update your post with an example of what you'd like the result to look like.

Comment: Added the data. The table displays properly in preview but not once posted. Not sure why. It's simple, though. One column of sums of the continuous variable. Rows for each level of the exposure variables (e.g. exposure 1 "yes" and "no", exposure 2 "yes" and "no").

Comment: can you add the example of what you want the table to look like? you can add a screenshot to the post

Comment: Thank you! I have added a link to an image in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you're after:

```r
library(gtsummary)
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      outcome_var = 
        structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                    1), levels = c("No", "Yes")),
      exposure_1 = 
        structure(c(1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                  levels = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), 
      exposure_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
                                                                                           "1"), class = "factor")), 
    class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                        -239L)) |> 
  dplyr::as_tibble()

df |> 
  tbl_continuous(
    variable = outcome_var,
    include = c(exposure_1, exposure_2),
    statistic = ~"{sum}",
    digits = ~0
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 239** |
| --- | --- |
| exposure_1 |  |
| 1 | 44 |
| 0 | 13 |
| Unknown | 1 |
| exposure_2 |  |
| 0 | 54 |
| 1 | 3 |
| Unknown | 1 |

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>